# SQL - insert and limit the number of entries

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, insert

I have a table that represents a user's entries:

```
User_ID | Entry_ID
```

Now I want to store only the last 20 entries (for example).

What would be the best way to insert new entries while keeping the maximum number of entries per user at 20 (new entries will replace oldest entries) ?

I need to be able to insert also a list of items to replace the old ones (if possible, to avoid multiple SQL requests)

Comment: Why dont you call a store procedure, in that SP delete old entries and insert new ones. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If a user has 17 entries and need to add 4 new entries, how do you choose which of the 17 gets deleted? Hint: you need a further column (`effective_date`, `sequence_number`) that is unique for each entry for each user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)...

Add a statement-level after insert trigger, which deletes rows like:

```
delete from yourtbl
where yourid not in (
  select yourid from yourtbl order by yourid desc limit 20
)
```